# How to create a Web data connector in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data service URL, which is giving me json data as an output. I want to import all the json data returned by URL to tableau for generating reports.

I am not able to create a web data connector to connect to that particular dataservice from tableau.

How can I create a WDC?

Answer (score 0):

Tableau's WDC [github](http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/) is a pretty awesome resource for you to create web data connector.  It even has some basic tutorials for you to create one.